# Не могу найти название виджета Android/iOS приложения

Tags: ios, android-sdk, flutter, android-widgets

Виджет выглядит как мульти-позиционный switch. Подскажите как называется?
[image: пример виджета]

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет TabBar

Comment: Вы правы - это оно и есть, спасибо! https://android.jlelse.eu/flutter-bubble-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-dd038f1076d3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще в iOS это UISegmentedControl. Его визуальный клон во Flutter [CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl-class.html)